# Formatting Dates retrieved by Breeze using moment.js. Hot Towel Template

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, hottowel, momentjs

I have been following John Papa's Hot Towel Tutorials and I have a c# class that looks like this:

```
public class Lead
{
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastContactMade { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastContactAttempt { get; set; }
}
```

I am retrieving the data in the client using breeze but I cannot figure out how to format the date using moment.js and knockout.js.  When I display the date un-formatted using the following knockout binding:

```
<section data-bind="foreach: leads">
    <span data-bind="text: lastContactMade"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: lastContactAttempt"></span>
</section>
```

The dates are displayed in the following format:

```
Wed Feb 27 2013 03:28:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

When I try to format them using moment.js as follows:

```
<section class="article-list" data-bind="foreach: leads">
    <span data-bind="text: moment(lastContactMade).format('l LT')"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: moment(lastContactAttempt).format('l LT')"></span>
</section>
```

the resulting output looks like this:

```
NaN/NaN/0NaN 12:NaN AM
```

I've also tried doing the formatting in my LeadInitializer located in my model (which is what I'd prefer) by doing this:

```
function leadInitializer(lead) {
    lastContactAttempt = lead.lastContactAttempt;
    lastContactMade = lead.lastContactMade;
    lead.lastContactAttempt = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return moment(lastContactAttempt).format('l LT');
        },
        write: function () {
            return lastContactAttempt;
        }
    });
    lead.lastContactMade = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return moment(lastContactMade).format('l LT');
        },
        write: function () {
            return lastContactMade;
        }
    });
};
```

Doing this, I still get the same output:

```
NaN/NaN/0NaN 12:NaN AM
```

i've read the post at

[Date formatting issues with Knockout and syncing to breeze.js entityAspect modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001303/date-formatting-issues-with-knockout-and-syncing-to-breeze-js-entityaspect-modif)

but it did not seem to help me here.  Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just forgot to unwrap the Knockout observables:

```
// add parentheses here......................vv
<span data-bind="text: moment(lastContactMade()).format('l LT')"></span>
<span data-bind="text: moment(lastContactAttempt()).format('l LT')"></span>
```

When you load an entity with Breeze, all the properties will be created as Knockout observables. You can use these observables directly in your `data-bind` Knockout bindings, but since moment.js won't know what to do with a Knockout observable, you have to first unwrap the observable to get the plain JavaScript Date value.